# How to stack a set of smaller DIVS adjacent to one big one using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve a layout like this.

```
 aaa xxxxxx oooo
 aaa xxxxxx oooo 
     xxxxxx 
     xxxxxx
 bbb xxxxxx cccc
 bbb xxxxxx cccc
     xxxxxx
     xxxxxx
```

I have tried using the float, and clear properties to place the Divs but in vain. Please help.

 The centre block will contain a logo and the surrounding four divs will have have navigation buttons. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you push your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position:absolute`?
Also you can use a `<table>` to do the same?